# Tablayout in Fragment not working in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a tabbed layout  as home fragment of navigation drawer activity,

so i called fragment named 'test' as default in main activity. like

```
        test home_fragment=new test();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, home_fragment,home_fragment.getTag()).commit();
```

if i call this fragment again . like

```
if (id == R.id.nav_home) {


        test home_fragment=new test();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, home_fragment,home_fragment.getTag()).commit();


    }
```

now the result is tab1 and tab2 are gone

See the screenshot for more reference

[image: When opening or calling for the first time]
[image: When opening or calling for the second time time]

this is my test class( tabbed layout)

```
 package com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.testapp;


 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import static android.R.attr.x;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class test extends Fragment {




public SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public ViewPager mViewPager;





public test() {


}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
   // View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,null);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new  SectionsPagerAdapter (getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab Title 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab Title 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    return rootView;

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:

                tab1 tab1=new tab1();

                return tab1;
            case 1:

                tab2 tab2=new tab2();

                return tab2;


            default:return null;
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";

        }
        return null;
    }
}



}
```

this is my tabbed layout xml code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.testapp.MainActivity"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this two solution:

**Solution 1**

instead of

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
```

use

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
```

**Solution 2**

use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new  SectionsPagerAdapter (getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: which is the best way ?

Comment: bro , i think u got the way i do programming, i don't know much, but i want to do more like you, so suggest me a way to become a good developer like you , thanks

Comment: i would prefer the first way...to be a Good developerr...i would say keep practicing code (Android) and read the different code samples and their work procedure..i would also suggest you to read official android developer documentation which helps me a lot in the way..